# Visual Studio 2012 - reporting "namespace not found" for autogenerated code but compiles and runs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've been plagued by this problem at work for months now, the VS intellisense/class-caching in silverlight projects just seem to lose contact with the autogenerated code base and reports every entity class as a missing namespace error.

**My code builds and runs OK and the errors only appear for the files that are open, i.e. if I close all my .cs files there are no errors in the error list.**

Please see the attached image for an example of what I see on a regular basis, I've just spent an hour trying to stop this because it's a nightmare as I can't spot real errors for all other namespace errors that VS2012 is reporting and my intellisense is completely broken.

Before you make a suggestion here is what I have just done in the last hour:

1 Cleaned the entire solution deleted all bin/obj/autogenerated directories
 2 Unloaded all the affected projects and reloaded them then repeated 1
 3 Restarted VS
 4 Reset my VS settings via Tools - Import Export Settings
 5 Closed VS, opened VS without a solution, reset settings, closed it and opened the solution
 6 Restarted my computer and repeated everything above

Please if anyone has any clues as to how to fix this I would be extremely happy!!

[image]

Comment: Is your framework building correctly? Have your tried re-install VS12? Otherwise I think it is something with your versions that Is wrong..

Comment: there are two other developers with exactly the same laptops/config/code-base and neither of them experience this... I've re-installed in the past and it's made no difference. And yes it is building and running - and build is fine on our TFS CI builds too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only remotely reliable way to fix this when it occurs is to remove the .web project and reload it. This seems to trigger vs to refresh the assemblies and the error messages go away. Previously I've focused on unloading then silverlight projects which was never very successful.

Comment: Really confused why unloading and reloading a project triggers something that rebooting your VS or closing / opening the solution does not. But it works... Thanks. In my case, it was a ASP.NET MVC project in VS2013.

Comment: I believe it's because the info is cached somehow in the VS Solution to make intellisense etc more efficient... by unloading and reloading it must force a rebuild of this... that's my guess